# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException On printing Pojo values

Tags: java, hibernate

Following are my pojo classes

```
public class BillDetails implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Long billNo;
    private CustomerDetails customerDetails;
    private Float subTotal;
    private Float vat;
    private Float total;
    private String paymentType;
    private String status;
    private Date addDate;
    private List billProductDetailses = new ArrayList();
 //getter and setter
}
public class BillProductDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private BillProductDetailsId id;
     private ProductDetails productDetails;
     private BillDetails billDetails;
     private long qty;
     private float unitPrice;
     private float sellingPrice;
     private Integer discountPercent;
    //getter and setter
}
public class ProductDetails  implements java.io.Serializable {
     private Long barcode;
     private ProductBrand productBrand;
     private Sizes sizes;
     private ProductModelDetails productModelDetails;
     private SupplierDetails supplierDetails;
     private Colors colors;
     private ProductTypes productTypes;
     private long quntity;
     private float unitPrice;
     private float sellingPrice;
     private Integer discountPercent;
     private Date addDate;
     private String status;
     private Set billProductDetailses = new HashSet(0);
//getter and setter
}
```

I have appropriate .hbm.xml file for all classes
Here I am trying to print details  of `BillProductDetails` and `ProductDetails` for that i am using following code

In BillDAO.java

```
public Map fetchAll(int start, int pageSize) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        List<BillDetails> obj = null;
        long count = 0;
        try {
            count = (Long) session.createQuery("select count(*) from BillDetails").uniqueResult();
            String hql = "from BillDetails as bd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.customerDetails as cd "
                    + "left join fetch bd.billProductDetailses as bpd "
                    + "left join fetch bpd.billDetails";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql).setFirstResult(start).setMaxResults(pageSize);
            obj = query.list();
            tx.commit();

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                tx.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        Map data = new HashMap();
        data.put("list", obj);
        data.put("count", count);
        return data;
    }
```

In following class I am printing values from classes

```
public class BillNewAction{
     public static void main(String[] s) {
            BillDAO dao = new BillDAO();
            Map m = dao.fetchAll(0, 10);

            List<BillDetails> billList = (List<BillDetails>) m.get("list");
            for (BillDetails d : billList) {
                System.out.println("bill no "+d.getBillNo() + "  paymentType " + d.getPaymentType());
                System.out.println("name "+d.getCustomerDetails().getName() + " address " + d.getCustomerDetails().getAddress() + " dob "
                        + d.getCustomerDetails().getDob() + "  anni " + d.getCustomerDetails().getAnniversery());
                List<BillProductDetails> bpd = d.getBillProductDetailses();
                System.out.println("bpd size is " + bpd.size());
                for (BillProductDetails cd : bpd) {
       /*Line 150*/             System.out.println("qty "+cd.getQty() + " sp " + cd.getSellingPrice() + " up " + cd.getUnitPrice());//Throwing nullPointer Exception
                    System.out.println(" barcode "+cd.getProductDetails().getBarcode() + "prType " + cd.getProductDetails().getProductTypes());

                }
            }

        }
}
```

Output of above program is

```
bill no 3  paymentType Cash
name manish address durg dob 2014-05-16  anni 2014-05-18
bpd size is 2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at iland.bill.BillNewAction.main(BillNewAction.java:150)
Java Result: 1
```

How to print values for above.

Comment: Could you show the class BillNewAction?, and tell us what is line 150

Comment: In main function I have edited question for line 150

Comment: Likely, some of the methods of `cd` you are calling are returning Null or `cd` itself is null. Check that `bpd` is initialized. And if you have the code for `BillNewAction`, posted it, please.

Comment: cd value is coming as null. Put debugger and see the value.

Comment: While checkin with debugger first list of BillProductDetails is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the line specified is 150, then `cd` is `null`. Please debug to  check the values in the list `bpd`. It means that the list `bpd` is having `null` value instead of  `BillProductDetails` instance. So, while iterating the elements on the list, `NPE` is thrown when `getQty()` method is invoked on the `null` reference

Comment: While printing it is showing bpd size is 2. means it is having two `BillProductDetails` value

Comment: No, the list size is 2. i.e. Technically, it has two `BillProductDetails` references in it. But, any of them may point to `null` as well. PS: `null` can be assigned to any reference type

Comment: While checkin with debugger first list of `BillProductDetails` is null

Comment: So, you mean the wholelist is `null`. But, you said the size of the list is 2

Comment: No `BillProductDetails[0]` is null

Comment: oh, ok. then, my answer is right. you will have to debug the method `getBillProductDetailses()` where you add the elements to the list

Comment: I am using Hibernate to fetch details in `billProductDetailses`

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, likely, some of the methods of `cd` you are calling are returning Null or `cd` itself is null. Check that `bpd` is initialized.

May be the problem comes from `getBillProductDetailses()`, you should make sure that all the methods you call `cd.getQty()` `cd.getSellingPrice()` are not returning null. But I would guess is `cd` being Null what causes you the problem.